# What is the best way to debug 'Illegal field name' in a Perl SOAP module?

Tags: perl, debugging, soap

I am attempting top virtualise an old system for a client.  This uses SOAP to pass data from the front end to the back end and back again.  All the code has been copied across and the relevant Perl modules installed from CPAN.  Most of the front end system works however when a SOAP call is made the system crashes, with this error in the API logs:

```
Illegal field name 'APR::Table=HASH(0x7fe19a0c41e0)' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/SOAP/Transport/HTTP2.pm line 103.
```

Looking at the module in question the section that is erroring is this one, with Line 103 being the `do {}` block:

```
  my $cl = ($self->{'MOD_PERL_VERSION'} == 1) ?
    $r->header_in('Content-length') : $r->headers_in->{'Content-length'};
  $self->request(HTTP::Request->new(
    $r->method() => $r->uri,
    HTTP::Headers->new($r->headers_in),
    do { my ($c,$buf); while ($r->read($buf,$cl)) { $c.=$buf; } $c; }
  ));
  $self->SUPER::handle;
```

I struggle a bit with OO Perl (I think in procedural ways) but as far as I can tell it's building an object where the method is the URI and then constructing headers in the `do{}` loop, appending them to `$c` and finally adding `$c` to the object.  I'm assuming it doesn't like one or more of the field names that the loop is returning, but when I tried to add debug to print the `$buf` variable to a file in /tmp as it looped it didn't generate any output.

In attempting to resolve this I came across this advice (though this relates to Transport::HTTP not the Transport::HTTP2 we are using): https://www.tnpi.net/support/forums/index.php?topic=1037.0  I've downgraded HTTP::Message to version 6.04, however the error remains.

So I'm wondering a) how to get some debug output to see what the problem actually is, and b) any suggestions as to how to get it to work?

Update 1 (responding to first reply):

Thanks for that!

It didn't seem to like that `my $data = do{}` section, so I went with this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my ($data);
open (L1, ">>/tmp/testlog1.txt");
print L1 "Starting to dump data...\n";
my $method = $r->method();
print L1 "Dumping \$r\n" . Dumper($r);
print L1 "Dumping \$method\n" . Dumper($method);
my $uri = $r->uri;
print L1 "\$method = $method => $uri\n";
my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new($r->headers_in);
print L1 "Dumping headers\n" . Dumper($headers);
```

Which produced the output below.

```
Starting to dump data...
Dumping $r
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = '140277572968608')}, 'Apache2::RequestRec' );
Dumping $method
$VAR1 = 'POST';
$method = POST => /
Dumping headers
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'HTTP::Headers' );
```

Should a variable really contain that "bless" construct?

Comment: The bless construct is a xs binding in perl. It's perfectly normal when dumping objects that are not perl objects. Did you try to get the data from $r->read and to create the request?

Comment: I know this is old but did you find a solution to the problem? I would be very interested, I am also migrating some very old stuff to a new platform.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this further try to debug what values you are sending to `$self->request`, and what command is actually causing the error.

I would try something like this (replacing the `$self->request` statement):

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $method = $r->method();
my $uri = $r->uri;
warn "$method => $uri";
my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new($r->headers_in);
warn Dumper($headers);
my $data; 
{ 
    my ($buf); 
    while ($r->read($buf,$cl)) { $data.=$buf; } 
}
warn "data: $data";

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
  $method => $uri,
  $headers,
  $data
);
warn Dumper($req);

$self->request($req);
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  This will have to be in several sections:

It didn't seem to like that `my $data = do{}` section, so I went with this:

    use Data::Dumper;
    my ($data);
    open (L1, ">>/tmp/testlog1.txt");
    print L1 "Starting to dump data...\n";
    my $method = $r->method();
    print L1 "Dumping \$r\n" . Dumper($r);
    print L1 "Dumping \$method\n" . Dumper($method);
    my $uri = $r->uri;
    print L1 "\$method = $method => $uri\n";
    my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new($r->headers_in);
    print L1 "Dumping headers\n" . Dumper($headers);

Which produced the output below.

Comment: Ignore above, it won't let me format it sensibly and now won't allow edits.  Will include response in original question.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Check on your configuration of the request headers, make sure the Content_Type (e.g. application/json; charset=utf-8) is the same as your Content (i.e. your post data).